# C++ Excel::RangePtr range_dataFloat - Expression must be a pointer to a complete object type

Tags: c++, excel, cplex

I am trying to export the below data to excel but it shows an error at the last line under `range_dataFloat`. This is the error I get:

> Excel::RangePtr - Expression must be a pointer to a complete object type

The rest of the code is working and connected to excel, but the problem is with this part:

```cpp
int SW1 [2] = { 0, 0 }; // South-West coordinate of the first square
int SE1 [2] = { 1, 0 }; // South-East coordinate of the first square
int NW1 [2] = { 0, 1 }; // North-West coordinate of the first square
int NE1 [2] = { 1, 1 }; // North-East coordinate of the first square

Excel::RangePtr range_dataFloat;

range_dataFloat = sheet_input -> GetRange (L"Coordinates");

int Square_Coordinates [i][j];

for ( i = 0 ; i < n_squares ; i++ ) // For loop to move to the next row
{
    int p = 1;

    // Changing the coordinates of the first square in each row
    SW1 [1] = i;
    SE1 [1] = i;
    NW1 [1] = i+1;
    NE1 [1] = i+1;

    range_dataFloat -> Item [p][p] = SW1[0];
```